# $AA^T = A^TA=I$ polynomial of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, determinant

If for a matrix $A \in M_3(R)$ we know that $AA^T=A^TA=I$ and $\det(A)=1$ is it true that $p_A(1)=0$? I am first supposed to say if this is true, than give an explanation, but I am really confused by this one. Any help is appreciated..

Comment: How is p_A defined?

Comment: Is $p_A$ the characteristic polynomial of $A$?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs yes, I think that it is the characteristic polynomial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer given is a nice direct approach.  A more typical idea is as follows:

The values $\lambda$ such that $p_A(\lambda) = 0$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.  We wish to show that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Note that $\det(A)$ is the product of the $3$ eigenvalues of $A$.  Because $A^TA = 1$, we know that all eigenvalues satisfy $|\lambda| = 1$.  Because $A$ is a matrix with real entries, all strictly complex eigenvalues (i.e. eigenvalues with non-zero imaginary part) must come in conjugate pairs.

Suppose that $A$ has real eigenvalues.  Then every eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ is from $\{\pm 1\}$, and we can confirm that $\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3 = 1$ implies that one of eigenvalues is $1$.

Suppose that $A$ has a strictly complex eigenvalue $\lambda_1$.  The conjugate $\lambda_2 = \overline{\lambda_1}$ must also be an eigenvalue.  The determinant is
$$
\det(A) = \lambda_1 \overline{\lambda_1}\lambda_3 = |\lambda_1|^2 \lambda_3 = \lambda_3
$$
since $\det(A) = 1$, the remaining eigenvalue must be $1$.

---

Here's another approach: write 
$$
p_A(\lambda) = \det(A - \lambda I) = -\lambda^3 + a_2\lambda^2 + a_1 \lambda + a_0
$$
This polynomial is a cubic, so it either has $3$ roots or one root.
 If it has $3$ roots, then it's easy to see that any real eigenvalue (i.e. any real root) of $A$ is $\pm 1$: suppose that $Ax = \lambda x$, where $\lambda$ is real.  Then 
$$
\|Ax\|^2 = \lambda^2 \|x\|^2
$$
but we also have $\|Ax\| = \|x\|$, which means that $\lambda^2 =1$, so $\lambda = \pm1$.

With that, we can use the above proof for the three real eigenvalue case as written.

Otherwise, consider the graph $y = p_A(x)$.    Suppose that $p_A(0) = 1$ and $p_A(-1) = 0$.  We know that $\lim_{x \to \infty}p_A(x) = - \infty$.  So, by the intermediate value theorem, $p_A$ has another root, which contradicts our assumption.

So, if $p_A$ has only one real root, and if $\det(A) = p_A(0) = 1$, then we must have $p_A(1) = 0$.

Comment: thank you! can you only explain how did you know that, based on the $A^TA=1$, all eigenvalues must satisfy $|\lambda |=1$ ?

Comment: The usual proof is as follows: let ${}^*$ denote the conjugate-transpose.  If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $x$, then $Ax = \lambda x$, and $(Ax)^* = \overline{\lambda}x^*$.  So, we see that
$$
\|Ax\|^2 = (Ax)^*(Ax) = \overline{\lambda}\lambda x^*x = |\lambda|^2 \|x\|^2
$$
on the other hand, we know that for any orthogonal matrix and any $x$, $\|Ax\| = \|x\|$.  So, we have
$$
|\lambda|^2 \|x\|^2 = \|x\|^2
$$
which implies that $|\lambda| = 1$. This is a tricky proof if you've never seen the conjugate-transpose.

Comment: An equivalent bit: since $A$ is orthogonal, 
$$
(Ax)^*(Ax)^* = x^*(A^*A)x = x^*(A^TA)x = x^*x = \|x\|^2
$$

Comment: Here's another approach: write 
$$
p_A(\lambda) = \det(A - \lambda I) = -\lambda^3 + a_2\lambda^2 + a_1 \lambda + a_0
$$
This polynomial is a cubic, so it either has $3$ roots or one root.
   If it has $3$ roots, then it's easy to see that any real eigenvalue (i.e. any real root) of $A$ is $\pm 1$, so we can use my proof as written. Otherwise, consider the graph $y = p_A(x)$.    Suppose that $p_A(0) = 1$ and $p_A(-1) = 0$.  We know that $\lim_{x \to \infty}p_A(x) = - \infty$.  So, by the intermediate value theorem, $p_A$ has another root, which contradicts our assumption.

Answer (score 8):

This is true. \begin{align} p_A(1) & = \det(A - I) \\ & = \det(A^T-I)\\ & =\det(A)\det(A^T-I)\\ & =\det(AA^T-A)\\ & =\det(I-A)\\ & =\det((-1)(I-A))\\ & =(-1)^3 \det(A-I) \\ & = -\det(A-I)\end{align}
So, $p_A(1) = 0$.